# How to pass argument to a Service?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

In Angular, I have two services: one that makes http requests (RequestService) and one that stores data/state (StateService).

If I need to perform a request with some data stored in StateService, should I simply inject StateService into RequestService and get the required data, or should I pass the required value as a parameter to the method performing the request?

What is considered better practise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the "right" answer depends pretty much on your coding philosophy. From my point of view I would argue that the services should stay as independent as possible --> pass the required parameter.

Doing this consequently can benefit you a lot,

- If you are working on a bigger project with different developers/teams that focus on delivering different functionality, but sharing services.
- If you are changing your StateService in the future, because your RequestService (that might be used by many other parties) can remain untouched.
- If you want to divide your application into different independent services later on.